# How to start view controller from non viewcontroller class

Tags: swift3, viewcontroller, nsobject

I want to open present uiviewcontroller from class that inherts from nsobject .how this work?
I tried this code

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginSignupVC")
self.present (initialViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code `self.present` wont work because you're inside a **NSObject** class.

So self refers to NSObject class.

**NSObject class doesn't have a method `present` in it.**

For presenting a view controller you must have a navigation controller as root.

Solution 1: So get the navigation controller using `self.navigationController` and present your view controller to it.

```
let initialViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginSignupVC") as! ViewController
self.navigationController!.presentViewController(initialViewController, animated: true)
```

Solution 2: Create a navigationcontroller manually and present in it.

```
let initialViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginSignupVC") as! ViewController
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: initialViewController) 
self.presentViewController(navController, animated:true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: NSObject  has no member 'presentViewController'

Comment: Make sure you are writing this code inside UIViewController class

Comment: My class is a non UIViewController class. Well, I figured that out though. Passed my ViewController instance from the previous class to this non UIViewController class and presented it using that object.